# Javascript assetName Decoding

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, javascript

I'm trying to figure out a reliable way to decode an assetName using JavaScript.

My current implementation is this:

```
function hexToBytes (hex) {
    if(!hex){
        return hex;
    } else {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(hex.length / 2);
        for (let i = 0; i !== bytes.length; i++) {
            bytes[i] = parseInt(hex.substr(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}

return new TextDecoder("UTF-8").decode(hexToBytes(encodedAssetName))
```

The above seems to be work most of the time but on occasion seems to stumble on some assetNames.

As an alternative, I've been trying to see if the `cardano-serialization-lib` has anything built in that can help.

The most I can find is this:

```
let assetName = Loader.Cardano.AssetName.new(Buffer.from(hex, 'hex'))
```

`assetName` then seems to only have 3 functions and the `name` function returns a `Uint8Array`, which when passed using `new TextDecoder().decode(assetName.name())` returns the same result as my current implementation.

Is the cardano-serialization-lib method the best way to decode assetNames or is there a better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: At this stage it looks like both methods work well, but the JS version is obviously lighter.

Comment: The asset names are not guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded. They are just a string of 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 1):

cardano-serialization-lib does pretty much everything for building and reading transactions and interacting with the webwallets.

Here is how you can extract all the asset names from the a user's wallet and process them to get the policyid, the assename hex value and the asset name string from each of the assets

This part `this.API.getUtxos()` reads all UTXOs from the user's wallet and `TransactionUnspentOutput` is a function from cardano-serialization-lib

```
    /**
     * Gets the UTXOs from the user's wallet and then
     * stores in an object in the state
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */

    getUtxos = async () => {

        let Utxos = [];

        try {
            const rawUtxos = await this.API.getUtxos();

            for (const rawUtxo of rawUtxos) {
                const utxo = TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(Buffer.from(rawUtxo, "hex"));
                const input = utxo.input();
                const txid = Buffer.from(input.transaction_id().to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex");
                const txindx = input.index();
                const output = utxo.output();
                const amount = output.amount().coin().to_str(); // ADA amount in lovelace
                const multiasset = output.amount().multiasset();
                let multiAssetStr = "";

                if (multiasset) {
                    const keys = multiasset.keys() // policy Ids of thee multiasset
                    const N = keys.len();
                    // console.log(`${N} Multiassets in the UTXO`)


                    for (let i = 0; i < N; i++){
                        const policyId = keys.get(i);
                        const policyIdHex = Buffer.from(policyId.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex");
                        // console.log(`policyId: ${policyIdHex}`)
                        const assets = multiasset.get(policyId)
                        const assetNames = assets.keys();
                        const K = assetNames.len()
                        // console.log(`${K} Assets in the Multiasset`)

                        for (let j = 0; j < K; j++) {
                            const assetName = assetNames.get(j);
                            const assetNameString = Buffer.from(assetName.name(),"utf8").toString();
                            const assetNameHex = Buffer.from(assetName.name(),"utf8").toString("hex")
                            const multiassetAmt = multiasset.get_asset(policyId, assetName)
                            multiAssetStr += `+ ${multiassetAmt.to_str()} + ${policyIdHex}.${assetNameHex} (${assetNameString})`
                            // console.log(assetNameString)
                            // console.log(`Asset Name: ${assetNameHex}`)
                        }
                    }
                }


                const obj = {
                    txid: txid,
                    txindx: txindx,
                    amount: amount,
                    str: `${txid} #${txindx} = ${amount}`,
                    multiAssetStr: multiAssetStr,
                    TransactionUnspentOutput: utxo
                }
                Utxos.push(obj);
                // console.log(`utxo: ${str}`)
            }
            this.setState({Utxos})
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Or you can take a look at my git repo with this code and other examples of cardano-serialization-lib: https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector

Answer (score 0):

I did use  `console.log(output.amount().multiasset().get(aadaTokenPolicy).get(aadaTokenName).to_str())` to transform output->Value->MultiAsset->Asset->AssetName->string.

For your case `.to_str()` might do the work.